# GDI+: Draw underlined space with DrawString

Tags: gdi+, drawstring

Hallo,

i want to draw a justified text in GDI+.
When this text is underlined I have a problem, with the DrawString method:
- If you give to this method a string with a whitespace and the format underlined, it draws nothing, because the space has no width.
- If you have a justified text the maybe spaces are wider than normal.

I found no solution to draw a underlined space with a special width.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

GDI+ will draw the underline up to the trailing whitespace, and this is normally a *desirable* thing compared to GDI TextOut's behavior; but if you append any invisible non-whitespace character to the string you pass to DrawString (like U+200B zero width space or even a control character like U+007F), then the last character will no longer be the space, and all spaces are underlined. This is less brittle than trying to calculate the line length yourself.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't particularly surprise me. That's the behavior I would expect. GDI+ will draw the underline as expected for spaces that appear in-line with a string of text. The problem is, a string that contains *only* whitespace has no length, and thus doesn't get underlined.

So, the question is, why do you need to draw underlined white space? What's wrong with `DrawLine`?

Comment: Hallo, thank you for the answer.

The reason, why I need to underline white spaces is the following:

I have something like my own edit-field. In this field I can type letters and so on.
In this edit-field you can also make some formatting definitions like alignment.

For example alignment justified needs to print all words in my edit-field separatly. So I calculate the width of the space and calculate the position of the words.

If the text should be underlined, of course the space between the text should also be underlined.